# OpenXML ASP.NET c#: tablecell vertical alignment issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to align the text in the tablecells of my `*.docx-documents`.
Everything goes fine until I append the `tablecellproperty` to the `tablecell` itself.

```
TableCell tc = new TableCell();

TableCellProperties tcpVA = new TableCellProperties();
TableCellVerticalAlignment tcVA= new TableCellVerticalAlignment() { Val = TableVerticalAlignmentValues.Center };
tcpVA.Append(tcVA);

tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct, Width = columnwidths[i] }), tcpVA);
```

Appending the `cellwidth`, color and so on works fine but it is just the `TableCellVerticalAlignment` that won't work.

The value for the TableCellProperty is set:

```
Val = "center"
```

But after appending the `TableCellProperties` to the `tablecell` the property for the `verticalalignment`:

```
TableCellVerticalAlignment = null
```

Answer (score 4):

You are adding two `TableCellProperties` to the `TableCell`, one for the vertical alignment and the other for the cell width. The schema only allows for one `TableCellProperties`.

The `TableCellVerticalAlignment` and `TableCellWidth` should both be appended to the *same* `TableCellProperties` and then only that `TableCellProperties` should be added to the cell.

The following method is an example that will create a document with a table that has a single cell with both the width and alignment properties set and the text "Hello World!" in it.

```
public static void CreateWordDoc(string filename)
{
    using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Create the document structure
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

        //add a table, row and column
        Table table = body.AppendChild(new Table());
        TableRow row = table.AppendChild(new TableRow());
        TableCell tc = row.AppendChild(new TableCell());

        //create the cell properties
        TableCellProperties tcp = new TableCellProperties();
        //create the vertial alignment properties
        TableCellVerticalAlignment tcVA = new TableCellVerticalAlignment() { Val = TableVerticalAlignmentValues.Center };
        //create the cell width
        TableCellWidth tcW = new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct, Width = "100" };
        //append the vertical alignment and cell width objects to the TableCellProperties
        tcp.Append(tcW);
        tcp.Append(tcVA);

        //append ONE TableCellProperties object to the cell
        tc.Append(tcp);

        //add some text to the cell to test.
        Paragraph para = tc.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello World!"));

        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```